# Working out radiation rates

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

Suppose the radiation dose of a CO-$57$ source was measured to be $63$ mR/hour $5$cm away from the source. Is there any way to measure the radiation at the source? ($0$cm from the source). I thought it would be $63$ mR/h * ($5$cm)^$2$ = $1575$ mR/h. But this logic doesn't correspond to other measurements I have.

At $3$ ft, the measured radiation dosage is $0.256$ mR/h, which would mean that at $1$ ft (~ $61$ cm closer to the source), the dosage should be somewhere around $0.256$ mR/h * ($61$cm)^$2$ = $953$ mR/h, whereas the measured dosage comes in nowhere near that at $2.31$ mR/h.

Does anybody know how to do that correctly? I am looking for the dosage at the source.

Comment: And just how big is the actual source? If $r$ is similar to the source size, why should the inverse square law hold?

Comment: @JonCuster the inverse square law seems to be conserved using the following calculator - http://www.radprocalculator.com/Gamma.aspx.

Also, what do you mean how big? rather small. The source is $5$ mCi.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by Jon Custer alludes to, this is actually a rather non-physical question. The inverse square law holds when one is at large distances to the source, compared to the size of the source itself.
Additionally, the process of radiation is inherently stochastic; and therefore the source dosage itself is a delta function, occurring at random (Poisson distributed) time intervals.

I know this is likely not the answer you intended to have but  one can only provide numerical values given certain (non-zero) distances from a source.

Comment: well even if it was stochastic there should be a way to compute, say, the expected value and variance at a small distance away from the source

Comment: Yes @Upbeet of course there is, by integrating over a solid angle from the point source at the origin. This will just be the mean emission rate times area, say $\lambda * 4 \pi r^2$. However the problem is then taking the limit $r \to 0$.

Comment: OK, well, if it measure $63$ mR/h at $5$ cm away from the source, is there a good way to gauge what the radiation would be $5$ cm closer to the source?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think so without more information. For instance, can you give any estimation of the size of the source? (nm, um, cm?)